# Cannot read property 'getMediaDevices' of undefined

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement QR scanner to scan for QR code using angular2-qrscanner. After doing what it says in the documentation,
I am gettting the error

> "Cannot read property 'getMediaDevices' of undefined "

on the console. These are my codes.

AppModule.ts

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import { NgQrScannerModule } from 'angular2-qrscanner';

 @NgModule({
 declarations: [AppComponent],
 imports: [
 BrowserModule,
 AppRoutingModule,
 NgMultiSelectDropDownModule,
 FormsModule,
 NgQrScannerModule,
 ],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent],
 })
 export class AppModule {}
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ViewEncapsulation, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { QrScannerComponent } from 'angular2-qrscanner';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild(QrScannerComponent) qrScannerComponent: QrScannerComponent;

ngOnInit() {
this.qrScannerComponent.getMediaDevices().then((devices) => {
  console.log(devices);
  const videoDevices: MediaDeviceInfo[] = [];
  for (const device of devices) {
    if (device.kind.toString() === 'videoinput') {
      videoDevices.push(device);
    }
  }
  if (videoDevices.length > 0) {
    let chosenDev;
    for (const dev of videoDevices) {
      if (dev.label.includes('front')) {
        chosenDev = dev;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (chosenDev) {
      this.qrScannerComponent.chooseCamera.next(chosenDev);
    } else {
      this.qrScannerComponent.chooseCamera.next(videoDevices[0]);
    }
  }
});
this.qrScannerComponent.capturedQr.subscribe((result) => {
  console.log(result);
});
}
}
```

.html

```
<qr-scanner
[debug]="false"
[canvasWidth]="1080"
[canvasHeight]="720"
[stopAfterScan]="true"
[updateTime]="500"
>
</qr-scanner>
```

this is the link to the documentation ===> https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-qrscanner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `ngAfterViewInit()`. It is called after the view is initially rendered. This is why `@ViewChild()` depends on it.

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.qrScannerComponent.getMediaDevices()
    ...
}
```

You can also try adding  `{ static: true }` to @ViewChild. If you set static true, the child component initialization will take place at the view initialization at `ngOnInit`

```
@ViewChild(QrScannerComponent, { static: true }) qrScannerComponent: QrScannerComponent;
```

Comment: I got this error after adding ngAfterViewInit  ===>                                                                        
          Class 'AppComponent' incorrectly implements interface 'OnInit'.
      Property 'ngOnInit' is missing in type 'AppComponent' but required in type 'OnInit'.

Comment: AppComponent doen't have ngOnInitby default, you have to add it

Comment: It is better now.  ngOnInit() {} . Thanks